# Netmiko Multiprocessing device exclusion/pending

Tags: python, netmiko

We are currently using netmiko 3.3.3 and some modules are using multiprocessing similar to the below;

```
with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
    results = executor.map(connect_and_complete_tasks, hosts)

    for result in results:
        print(result)
```

Some issues occur with this technique such as hitting a maximum lockout threshold on devices - I was wondering if there is a way to control the processes such that we can prevent connecting to the same device twice or wait until the previous process has finished or if anyone has a similar problem/solution.

Thanks